# Apache random slow image loading

Tags: wordpress, image, performance, apache

I have a weird issue on my sites where some images load slow. I have caching in place (CloudFlare caching, Brotli compression enabled), this is referring to the first "uncached" load. All of the images have been compressed to the maximum extent.

I'm wondering why some of the images have such a delay on the first load and if there's anything I can do to fix it.

Here's the network result from a site I didn't have cached.

[image: Chrome devtools networking result]

As you can see, it doesn't seem to matter how large the images are. Some larger ones load faster, while some smaller ones are delayed.

Apache Global Configuration settings are as follows (default):

```
Start Servers 5
Minimum Spare Servers 5
Maximum Spare Servers 5
Server Limit 256
Max Request Workers 150
Max Connections Per Child 10000
Keep-Alive On
Keep-Alive Timeout 5
Timeout 300
```

Is there some configuration needed to allow these images to all resolve quickly? The CPU usage when loading my sites (uncached) is minuscule, it never goes over 1%.

In total, I count 17 images (all under 5kb) loading on this particular site.

I understand that Ngix/Litespeed would probably speed up the loading, but this question is strictly related to Apache 2.4+, without either of those installed.

Digital Ocean $20 droplet (2x CPUs - Intel E5-2650 v4, 4gb ram, 80gb ssd).

Apache 2.4+/CentOS/cPanel 90.

Edit: Removing the Apache cache headers and relying on only Cloudflare solved the "random delay". But still the question remains, why does the first "uncached" version take so long to load small images?

Comment: By a "first uncached load" you mean browser side, right?

I would first compare the response headers from a fast image load request and a slower one. To be sure Cloudflare actually serves a cached version of both images.

Comment: @Jiwoks I'm referring to after the Cloudflare cache has expired. I.e., when I first turn on my PC, with all browser cache cleared and the CF cache expired, the very first load of the day. However you may be on to something there, as the images that load are all "MISS" status by Cloudflare.

Comment: @Jiwoks I may have fixed it by removing the cache headers from my Apache config files... it seems that perhaps they were messing with CF's cache control and it was causing problems. I will try turning the cache on CF to longer amount.